# Numpy matrix multiplication causing windows exception

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ipython, spyder

This morning I updated my anaconda environment in the usual way using `conda update --all`. This seems to have broken matrix multiplication in Numpy. During the update Spyder, of which I use the iPython console to run this code, was updated from version 5.2.2.0 to version 5.2.2.2. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyHnC.png) is the the update report generated by anaconda. Furthermore, I am running Python version 3.9.10, iPython version 7.31.1 and Numpy version 1.22.2 on a windows 10 machine.

Every time I try to run either `np.dot(A, B)`, `np.matmul(A, B)` or `A @ B` with square two-dimensional Numpy arrays I get a Windows fatal exception with code 0xc06d007e. But when either `A` or `B` are one-dimensional arrays, the matrix multiplication works as expected. Below I show a minimal code snippet reproducing this:

```
Python 3.9.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  1 2022, 21:22:07) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.31.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In[1]: import numpy as np

In[2]: dims = 1

In[3]: N = 30

In[4]: A = np.arange(N**dims).reshape(*[N]*dims)

In[5]: B = np.eye(N)

In[6]: B @ A
Out[6]:
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.,
       13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25.,
       26., 27., 28., 29.])

In[7]: dims = 2

In[8]: A = np.arange(N**dims).reshape(*[N]*dims)

In[9]: B @ A


Windows fatal exception: code 0xc06d007e


Main thread:
Current thread 0x00003934 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\timvr\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18916\2990787033.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel...
```

I've tracked the error to the `@array_function_from_c_func_and_dispatcher(_multiarray_umath.dot)` decorator decorating the definition of `dot` in `ENVIRONMENT_PATH\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py`.

Comment: I suppose it is better to create a bug ticket in `numpy`, since the code does work in general (just checked).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by reinstalling Spyder, Numpy and their dependencies. After each reinstall I ran the code in my original question to see if anything had broken yet. The list of packages that I manually reinstalled after uninstalling Spyder and Numpy were:

0. Numpy
1. Scipy
2. Spyder
3. Uncertainties
4. QCodes
5. QuTip
6. HDF5
7. PyQTGraph
8. LMFit